# Async rabbitmq consumer with socket connect_ex

Tags: python, sockets, rabbitmq, python-asyncio

I want to write a python program that gets ip and tcp port from a rabbitmq server and scans to check if the port is open, as these scans sometimes come in bulk (maybe 100 port, ip pairs are added to the queue at a time) I need to do the scans asynchronously to get all the results in time, and even if I lower the timeout to 1 second, 30 closed ports will hold the scan for 30 seconds each time!
I tried asyncio and aio_pika to reach my goal but still the scans are being performed synchronously.

```
import asyncio
import aio_pika
import socket


async def tcp_check(host, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    result = sock.connect_ex((host,port))
    print (str(result))

async def main(loop):
    connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust("amqp://user:password@192.168.1.100/")
    async with connection:
        queue_name = "tcp_scans"
        channel = await connection.channel()
        queue = await channel.declare_queue(queue_name, auto_delete=False, durable=True)
        async with queue.iterator() as queue_iter:
            async for message in queue_iter:
                async with message.process():
                    context = message.body.decode("utf-8").split(',')
                    await tcp_check(context[0], int(context[1]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
    loop.close()
```

UPDATE:

I used asyncio.open_connection too:

```
async def tcp_check(host, port):
    con = asyncio.open_connection(host, port, loop=loop)
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(con, timeout=1)
        print("{}:{} Connected".format(host, port))
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print ("{}:{} Closeed".format(host, port))
```

Still it takes each item from the and test one by one...

Comment: Note that if you have a function defined with `async def`, such as `tcp_check`, you almost certainly want to `await` something in it. If you're not awaiting anything, it means that either the function shouldn't be async in the first place, or you accidentally invoked a blocking API (such as `connect_ex`).

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to fix my problem

Comment: What Alex said in the answer and in the comments applies: you need a really async `tcp_check` and you need to pass the coroutines to something like `gather` instead of awaiting them directly in the loop (which just runs them sequentially). Google gather and aiohttp, there are many examples how to parallelize http fetches, and the same logic applies to your case too.

Answer (score 0):

Calling of synchronous long running functions inside asynchronous coroutines should be avoided. I'd suggest to use asyncio alternative to connect_ex, e.g.:

```
    try:
        await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

In order to execute some coroutines simultaneously "on the fly" you can use `create_task` that "wrap the coroutine into a Task and **schedule** its execution" as it is written in [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task). And after this, coroutine will be executed soon, e.g. after next `await` or `async for` iteration, when control flow returns to the event-loop.
`create_task` return `Task` object which you can add to list and wait them all finished using `asyncio.gather` with flag `return_exceptions=True`.
But in your case i think it will be sufficient replace `await tcp_check()` to `create_task(tcp_check())` and use `gather` at the end of your main() to guarantee all coro is finished.

```
...
asyncio.create_task(tcp_check(context[0], int(context[1])))
...
```

Comment: I don't get it! the point of async is not to wait for a long running task like checking a closed tcp port.

Comment: Try to `create_task` instead of `await` of tcp_check and then wait all tasks using `asyncio.gather`

Comment: Can you explain more?
As far as I understood, asyncio.gather needs some tasks to run simultaneously. How can I add these tasks on the fly... I mean fetch from queue and add the task(s)